# Javascript Variable Getting Assigned by PHP Causing Infinite Refreshes

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code.

```
<?php $location=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
<script>var location = <?php echo json_encode($location); ?>;</script>
```

This code causes an infinite amount of browser refreshes. If I remove the second line, everything works fine. I need to know potential causes for this, as I have no idea where to search. No Javascript is utilizing the variable named location currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your variable `location` is colliding with the global [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) object.

Quote from MDN:

> Though `Window.location` is a *read-only* Location object, you can also assign a DOMString to it. This means that you can work with `window.location` as if it were a string in most cases: `window.location = 'http://www.example.com'` is a synonym of `window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com'`

Since global variables are properties of the `window` object, `location` is the same as `window.location` here, and so you are telling the browser to replace the current page with that loaded from the “new” address assigned (which happens to be same address again in this case here).

Simply use a different variable name.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I don't know why my question warranted negative votes. I will check this out.